# Optimal process for finding the root of high load

Tags: monitoring, vps, system-monitoring

I have a VPS (WHM/cPanel) where i keep our clients projects.

Some of these projects are well known frameworks and some of them are custom PHP/MySQL codes.

At certain times i am noticing high loading but i can't really find where is the cause.

I am using `top -c` to check the top processes and have also installed Munin on WHM.

I would like to ask if there is a certain way to monitor in real time the causes of the high load.

At the time of high load, i am following these steps:

- Check global traffic and system resources
- Check Apache/MySQL/PHP logs
- Check which project causes the high load (usually from `top`)
- Go on a full stack trace of the code causing the high load

Is there a software that can do all of that in a central place? Is this the right way? What do you do in these situations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optimal process involves many tools that can give you a detailed view over the server.
The more informations you can get, from different sources, the easy will be to identify the cause.

You can check the logs for any problems that occurs during the time when this happens.
As well, some basic informations are available in Munin.

As well, you can install [NewRelic](http://newrelic.com/) to have a more clear picture over the process list and I/O status during the high load. This will show you which project caused the high load.

As well, you can check [logstash](http://logstash.net/) for logs or [logentries](https://logentries.com/)

You mention that you also use well known frameworks. Check if you are allocating enough RAM for them. I presume that most of them use a database. Is the DB server installed on the same machine? Is it on a dedicated machine? 
Are you using any sort of caching (Varnish, APC, etc..) ?

Comment: Thank you Andy, DB is on the same server. It's not dedicated. And we are not using any Cache method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install mytop and monitor all the queries that are running on your server , it is very handy and I often use it , also give a try at jetprofiler for mysql which you can download it here : http://www.jetprofiler.com/